# How can I change the title of a Google Chrome tab that is a pdf, new tab, or anything but a conventional http: or https: link?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For the permissions in manifest.json, I put

```
"permissions": 
   [
   "activeTab",
   "tabs",
   "http://*/*",
   "https://*/*"
   ]
```

and in my js file is used

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(currTab.id,{code:"document.title = '"+str+"'"});
```

where currTab was a tab object and str was the title I wanted.

The extension changed all titles other than new tabs, pdfs, and chrome webstore pages.